# How to perform maths arithmetic function?

Tags: sql, sql-server

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdxPd.png)

Find : `max - min / min * 100`

```sql
SELECT 
    *,
    MAX(Salary),
    MIN(Salary),
    MAX(Salary) - MIN(Salary)
FROM 
    Salary
GROUP BY
    empid
```

How to perform `/` operation ?

```sql
SELECT 
    *,
    MAX(Salary),
    MIN(Salary),
    ((MAX(Salary) - MIN(Salary)) / MIN(Salary))
FROM 
    Salary
GROUP BY
    empid
```

This is showing zero zero

Comment: I've gone ahead and removed the tag spam here;  please [edit] your question to (re)tag the actual (R)DBMS you are using. [Why does tagging multiple RDBMS products make my question unclear?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423302)

Comment: In *most* of the RDBMS you spammed in the tags those queries would error, as you try to return *every* column but only `GROUP BY` one.

Comment: usually you need to cast amounts to FLOATs or NUMERICs to be able to divide without integer division being in place. try replacing salary with `CAST(Salary as NUMERIC(19,0))`

Comment: To `float`s, @siggemannen ? I hope not with a Salary.

Comment: Not to mention: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

I got the zeroes when trying your query in SQLite3 when I declared the Salary as `INTEGER`. You haven't shown the declaration of the table, though, so it's just a guess.

What helped was to cast the divisor as real:

```sql
SELECT empid, MAX(Salary), MIN(Salary),
       ((MAX(Salary) - MIN(Salary)) / CAST(MIN(Salary) AS REAL))
FROM Salary
GROUP BY empid;
```

But if you need to result multiplied by 100, you can just multiply the subtraction before doing the division:

```sql
SELECT empid, MAX(Salary), MIN(Salary),
       100 * (MAX(Salary) - MIN(Salary)) / MIN(Salary)
FROM Salary
GROUP BY empid;
```

Comment: A float is a terrible data type for someone's salary. Monetary values and base 2 numbers *do not* mix without rounding issues.

Comment: I have no idea what` (MAX-MIN)/MIN` should represent, but to get anything other than 0 from it for numbers that are not too different, I don't see any other way.

Comment: `numeric`? I *assume* SQLite supports non-integer base-10 values; pretty sure all the other RDBMS the OP spammed do. Though it's still not clear what RDBMS the OP is using.

Comment: @ThomA: Sorry? Also, please see the update.

Comment: Using `NUMERIC` instead of `REAL` still returns the zeros.